# Error:(137, 20) error: unreachable statement

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  //return true;
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
  mif.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because return is the last line/statement executed in any method... all that is written after that is dead code and makes no sense since it can not be executed...

you should instead

```
MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
mif.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu,menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```